# match values between 2 arrays and arrange in new array

Tags: arrays, powershell

So I have 2 arrays

array1

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

array2  (aa  5) that's one element in the array and so on

```
aa  5
bb  4
cc  6
dd  8
ee  9
ff  10
gg  7
hh  11
```

What I want to do is to arrange letters in array2 to match numbers in array one and get that in a new array so output would be like this.

array3

```
bb
aa
cc
gg
dd
ee
ff
hh
```

```
 $array1 | %{

       if ($array2 -match $_) {

        array1 | select-string -pattern '(\w\w)'| % {$_.Matches.groups[1].value}


        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Please add to the question)

Comment: tried the above but no luck can't grasp it in my mind how to match then arrange, like if i match a 4 then i get bb next to it and keep on looping on in such manner to get all values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the solution using hashtable.

```
$array1 = 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

$array2 = @"
aa  5
bb  4
cc  6
dd  8
ee  9
ff  10
gg  7
hh  11
"@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

# create hashtable
$h = @{}
$array2 | foreach { $val, $key = $_ -split "\s+"; $h.Add([int]$key, $val) }

$array3 = $h[$array1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was really helpful

Comment: I am glad to help you.